# A simple connect-wall puzzle

Tags: connect-wall

<sup>*This is an entry in the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fortnightly-topic-challenge-41-short-and-sweet).*</sup>

---

Separate the words into four categories of four words each. Then take a chance at my favorite board game.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|No, it's not one of the CategoRies. That wouLd be too easy.}
\hline
\mathrm{Age}&\mathrm{Fast}&\mathrm{Country}&\mathrm{Through}\\
\hline
\mathrm{Iron}&\mathrm{Fresh}&\mathrm{Reason}&\mathrm{Hat}\\
\hline
\mathrm{Dance}&\mathrm{Ship}&\mathrm{Hole}&\mathrm{Pride}\\
\hline
\mathrm{Wheelbarrow}&\mathrm{Nickel}&\mathrm{Mailbox}&\mathrm{Touch}\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: this is still unsolved... maybe a hint is needed? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Partial possible answer, maybe it will help others

Group 1:

> Monopoly (your favorite board game?) pieces
>  hat, ship, wheelbarrow, iron

Group 2:

> words that are still words with "break" in front of them
>  (break)age, (break)dance, (break)fast, (break)through

Group 3:

> Things that have flags
>  country, hole (golf), mailbox, pride (rainbow flag?)

Group 4:

> that leaves the following.  I want to say face or head, but can't quite make it work
>  reason, touch, fresh, nickel